# How to differentiate between UDP Broadcasts and Unicasts?

Tags: networking, udp, winsock, broadcast

I have an Application (written in C/C++) thats communicating over UDP between many Windows and Linux Hosts inside the local Network (via winsock / Linux-Sockets). I only use one Port and so only one Socket on each host. Some messages are Broadcastet, replies are often Unicast but some are Broadcasts too. Everthing is working so far but:

How can i find out whether a Paket i received (via recvfrom) was a Broadcast or Unicast?

The only solution i found was to send this info inside the Payload or to use different ports. Both are not very nice...

Comment: You can actually trick people anyway, by broadcasting at the Ethernet layer and using a Unicast adddress at the IP layer or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux side you can set `PKT_INFO` [`ip(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html) socket option with [`setsockopt(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html), and then use [`recvmsg(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) to get the destination address of the UDP packet.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. On Windows `WSARecvMsg` does the job. Thank You!