# Getting information about received UDP message is broadcast or unicast

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

Good day, everyone!

I'm developing a Python module that allows client devices to be discovered and configured over local IP network using UDP socket.
I'm building my solution based on an existing protocol so it can be used with already existing software, but which enables the use of only one port.
Thus I can't solve the problem by using different ports for different message types.
But the protocol's security greatly depends on which request should be accepted or denied, based on whether the request was addressed to broadcast or to the device directly.

**My main problem is: I can't find a way (in Python) to differ broadcast messages from unicast ones (received on the same port/socket).**

In addition I'm looking for solutions for both Linux and Windows.
Furthermore on some (embedded, OpenWrt) devices that have to run this service, installing modules written in cPython is difficult, so I strongly prefer to using only built-in resources on the Linux side.
I am also stuck in using Python but if it cannot be helped, I can utilize external tools too.

I'd be glad for any help or guidance.
(This is my first post on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2):

linux has a socket option (`SO_PKTINFO`) that is actually ideal for this -- it will report exactly who the datagram was sent to. The man page for it says that it is linux-only. However, the windows [WSARecvMsg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687(v=vs.85).aspx) page seems to indicate that it's supported there too.

See also this answer: [How to differentiate between UDP Broadcasts and Unicasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667647/how-to-differentiate-between-udp-broadcasts-and-unicasts?rq=1)

If that will not suffice, the easiest way to accomplish this is to create two sockets on the receiving side. Both can use the same port, but will be bound to different addresses. For example, let's say your local IP address is 192.168.0.100. Then you create two sockets: one bound to the local IP and the other bound to the broadcast address.

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
from select import select

usock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
usock.bind(('192.168.0.100', 9999))

bsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
bsock.bind(('255.255.255.255', 9999))

while True:
    rrdy, wrdy, xrdy = select([usock, bsock], [], [])
    if usock in rrdy:
        in_msg, in_addr = usock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("Got unicast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
    if usock in rrdy:
        in_msg, in_addr = bsock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("Got broadcast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
```

This definitely works on linux. I don't know for certain it will work on Windows but it seems reasonable to expect that it would.

I'm using `select` here to receive messages from either socket, but you could easily spin off a separate thread for one of the ports if that were easier to manage.

Comment: Cool answer, I'm surprised you have got no credit for it.  OP: [accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank You for the fast and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to solve my problem.
Hamilton's answer was very appropriate and brought the solution closer, but as he mentioned it may not work (and wont) on Windows.
The Linux solution is almost working on both but there's a few very annoying differences with Wondows sockets:

- You **can't** bind a socket to a broadcast address. (neither of `n.n.n.255` or `255.255.255.255` works)
- You can bind a socket to the anycast (`0.0.0.0`) or any valid local address and it will receive only unicast messages.
- If you set the socketopt `SO_BROADCAST` before bind, it will receive unicast and broadcast messages as well (and you won't tell the difference).
- If you want to bind multiple sockets to the same port, you must set the socketopt `SO_REUSEADDR` on all sockets.
- If you construct a unicast and a "bothcast" socket and bind to the same port, you end up both receiving the unicast messages.
- If you using `select` (fed by these two sockets as in the Linux example) and they receiving the same unicast message, the `select` only gives back one in the first round. (it's a personal experiment with Windows 10)

I ended up with this workaround:

```
import platform
from socket import gethostbyname, gethostname, socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, SO_REUSEADDR
from select import select

PORT = 9999
myPublicIP = gethostbyname(gethostname())
platform = platform.system()

bsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
usock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

if platform == 'Windows':
    usock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 0)  # This isn't necessary
    usock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    bsock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    bsock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    usock.bind(('', PORT))
    bsock.bind(('', PORT))
    # empty string means anycast
elif platform == 'Linux':
    # on Linux SO_BROADCAST only affects the sending
    usock.bind((myPublicIP, PORT))
    bsock.bind(('255.255.255.255', PORT))

while True:
    # This is the tricky part
    select([bsock, usock], [], [])
    # if a bcast msg received the first select gives back only the usock instead of both
    ready = select([bsock, usock], [], [])[0]
    # the second select will give back both at the same time
    if bsock in ready and usock in ready:
        bmsg = bsock.recvfrom(1024)
        umsg = usock.recvfrom(1024)
        in_msg, in_addr = bmsg
        print("Got broadcast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
        if bmsg != umsg:
            in_msg, in_addr = umsg
            print("Got unicast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
    else:
        if bsock in ready:
            in_msg, in_addr = bsock.recvfrom(1024)
            print("Got broadcast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
        if usock in ready:
            in_msg, in_addr = usock.recvfrom(1024)
            print("Got unicast msg", in_msg, "from", in_addr)
```